# Android 4.0 based Virtual Box emulator can't detect Bluetooth 4.0 from Laptop

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth, virtualbox

Currently I am working on Android application which is communicates with the Bluetooth 4.0 Device. As of now, I included **broadcom-ble** in my application and did some sample codes. Actually I don't have Bluetooth 4.0 based Android Smart phone , so for the testing purpose I just Installed Oracle Virtual Box and used **android-x86-4.0-RC2.iso** in it. I can successfully run some sample Bluetooth based android application on Virtual Box. The problem is  Virtual Box can find Bluetooth 2.0 from my laptop. but when I try to use Bluetooth 4.0 , VM can't detect Bluetooth 4.0 . My Laptop have Bluetooth 4.0, but VM machine can't find Bluetooth 4.0. I was Installed **android-x86-4.0-RC2.iso** on Virtual Machine. How can I make my Android 4.0 Virtual machine can detect Bluetooth 4.0 from my Laptop.

Note: I was successfully detected Bluetooth 2.0 from Laptop using the same Android 4.0 VM, the problem is only for Bluetooth 4.0 . I am using Sony Vaio which contains Bluetooth 4.0.

Kindly some one help me please.

Comment: What error you are getting when trying to connect?

Comment: I have the same issue by vmware and built-in bluetooth smart ready. I guess the problem is with the android iso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem maybe is on the USB, because when you are using the laptop bluetooth, Virtual Box takes your laptop bluetooth as a USB Device. Upgrade the Oracle VM version, it will solve the problem.